# Initialize SSL to use TLSv1.2 instead of TLSv1.0 with Pocco C++ libraries

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

Our client software is failing to authenticate with the server because the server side no longer supports TLSv1.0.  We need to update the client to force it to use TLSv1.2, what is needed to accomplish this?  Is it as simple as changing `CLIENT_USE` to `TLSV1_2_CLIENT_USE`?  The poco library version is 1.7.8.

The current ssl initialization code is:

```
int poco_options = Poco::Net::Context::OPT_DEFAULTS;

if (bBypassSSLRevocationCheck)
{
    poco_options = Poco::Net::Context::OPT_TRUST_ROOTS_WIN_CERT_STORE | Poco::Net::Context::OPT_USE_STRONG_CRYPTO;
}


Poco::Net::initializeSSL();
Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler> certificateHandler = new Poco::Net::RejectCertificateHandler(false);
Poco::Net::Context::Ptr pocoContext = new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "", Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_RELAXED, poco_options);
Poco::Net::SSLManager::instance().initializeClient(NULL, certificateHandler, pocoContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using Poco 1.7.8, you will only be able to use `Poco::Net::Context::TLSV1_2_CLIENT_USE`.

This means the code would look like:

```
Poco::Net::Context::Ptr pocoContext = new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::TLSV1_2_CLIENT_USE, "", Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_RELAXED, poco_options);
```

For Poco 1.10 and newer, the preferred mechanism is to create the context using `TLS_CLIENT_USE`, and then setting the minimum protocol version, such as:

```
Poco::Net::Context::Ptr pocoContext = new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::TLS_CLIENT_USE, "", Poco::Net::Context::VERIFY_RELAXED, poco_options);
pocoContext.requireMinimumProtocol(Poco::Net::Context::PROTO_TLSV1_2);
```